# What is the gauge covariant derivative?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, differentiation, yang-mills

What is the [gauge covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative) in layman's? Does it describe the kinetic energy of the gauge fields?